# <g:remoteForm> redirect is not happening

Tags: ajax, grails

I am using a  to handle a login. In the case of incorrect credentials, I use Ajax to print an error message on the same web page but in the case of success I would like to forward to another web page. What is happening is that even in the case of success it is printing results on the same page. I know that this has partially to do with the fact that you can't send a redirect to Ajax. However, still a newbie to know how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Here is my gsp section having to do with this form:

```
<g:formRemote name="subForm" url="[controller:'admin', action:'authenticate']" update =        "error_message">
      <br><br><label>User Name (email): </label><g:textField name = "username" /><br><br>
      <label>Password: </label><g:field name = "password" type = "password" /><br><br><br><br>
      <div id = "error_message" style = "text-align: center"> </div>
      <div style = "text-align: center">(for TWC employees only)</div>
      <g:submitButton id = "submit_button" name="Submit"/>
    </g:formRemote>
```

and here is the controller method 'authenticate':

```
def authenticate = {

     try {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("admin");
            def userName = params.username
            def passWord = params.password
            boolean auth = db.authenticate(userName, passWord.toCharArray())                

            if (auth)
                redirect (action: loggedin)
            else {
                render "Login or Password incorrect!"
            }
     }
     catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (MongoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

def displayerror = {
    render "Login or Password incorrect!"
}

def loggedin = {}
```

As it is, I can't get the gsp corresponding to the 'loggedin' method to display. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor adjustments needed to previous poster's most helpful suggestions. This is the code that will actually solve the issue.

```
<g:formRemote name="subForm" url="[controller:'admin', action:'authenticate']" onSuccess="doResult(data)">
      <br><br><label>User Name (email): </label><g:textField name = "username" /><br><br>
      <label>Password: </label><g:field name = "password" type = "password" /><br><br><br><br>
      <div id = "error_message" style = "text-align: center"> </div>
      <div style = "text-align: center">(for TWC employees only)</div>
      <g:submitButton id = "submit_button" name="Submit"/>
    </g:formRemote>
```

javascript below:

```
function doResult(data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            window.location.href = data.url;
        } else {
            $("#error_message").html(data.message);
        }
    }
```

controller code section below

```
//success case
                render(contentType: 'text/json') {
                    [success: true, url: createLink(controller: 'whateverController', action: 'whateverAction')]
                }
            }
            else {
                render(contentType: 'text/json') { 
                    ["success": false, "message": 'Login or Password is incorrect.']
                }
```

importing JSON converter in last set of code isn't needed either.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you can't send a redirect using ajax. What you can do, however, is send something back in your ajax response that you can read and redirect if needed.

Instead of just updating the div with the response from your ajax call you will need to send back some JSON data and use the `onSuccess` attribute of the `formRemote` tag to pass the results to a function which can act accordingly.

I would suggest you start by reading over the documentation for the [formRemote](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) tag, then consider something like the following:

```
<g:formRemote name="subForm" url="[controller:'admin', action:'authenticate']" onSuccess="doResult(e)">
      <br><br><label>User Name (email): </label><g:textField name="username" /><br><br>
      <label>Password: </label><g:field name="password" type="password" /><br><br><br><br>
      <div id="error_message" style="text-align: center"> </div>
      <div style="text-align: center">(for TWC employees only)</div>
      <g:submitButton id="submit_button" name="Submit"/>
    </g:formRemote>
```

Notice in the above that `onSuccess` is now set on the `formRemote` tag and `update` is removed. The response from the form submission will now be passed to the javascript function `doResult`.

This is what the function might look like:

```
<script>
  function doResult(response) {
    var result = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
    if (result.success == true) {
      window.location.href = result.url;
    } else {
      $("#error_message").html(result.message);
    }
  }
</script>
```

The only thing left is to change how your controller responds to the form submission. First you will need to add the import for `import grails.converters.JSON` into your controller. Then change the way it responds. It might look like this:

```
import import grails.converters.JSON
...
// in the case of an error
render [success: false, message: "Login or Password incorrect!"] as JSON
return
...
// in the case of success
render [success: true, url: createLink(controller: 'whateverController', action: 'whateverAction')] as JSON
return
```

It may seem like a lot to take in all at once, but once you do it a few times it becomes quite simple. One thing that helps a lot is to read the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/index.html). It's long, but it's very well written and will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for such a well composed explanation. I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet. I did read the grails documentation and I understand the order of the Ajax communications now. I implemented what you have outlined above but have not yet achieved the desired result. Upon hitting the submit button, chrome's debugger complains that                                                           Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined adminlogin:49
jQuery.ajax.success adminlogin:49

Comment: j jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
x jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
b jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4  This at least tells me that jQuery is loading properly and the Ajax request did get fired right? The 'e' its complaining about is the argument to the "doresult(d)" function that you defined in your html sample above. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Sorry the comment above is broken into two submissions due to comment length limitations.

Comment: No worries, try renaming it to something else such as doResult(data), or even doResult() without a parameter being passed or simply doResult without the parens or parameter. I haven't used the formRemote in such a long time I can't recall the correct format. :/

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Changing to 'data' both in "doResult(e)" and in the function definition header got me further along to having trouble with the line:                             var result = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');     in which i changed the first instance of the word 'response' to 'data' also. The debugger is complaining that result is undefined. Im guessing its not being evaluated because in the next line which reads,  "if (result.success == true)..." , it says "can't read property success of undefined". Thanks for all your expert help.